# Execution of request failed: https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/private/full

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to add an event to a Google calendar by accepting the event details from a winform

while trying to add the event i'm getting the following error 
"Execution of request failed: https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/private/full"

the code is as follows :

```
        CalendarService myService = new CalendarService("exampleCo-exampleApp-1");
        myService.setUserCredentials("username@gmail.com", "password");


        EventEntry entry = new EventEntry();

        entry.Title.Text = textBox1.Text;
        entry.Content.Content = textBox2.Text;
        Where eventLocation = new Where();
        eventLocation.ValueString = textBox3.Text;
        entry.Locations.Add(eventLocation);

        When eventTime = new When();
        eventTime.StartTime =Convert.ToDateTime(textBox4.Text);
        entry.Times.Add(eventTime);

        Uri postUri = new Uri("http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/private/full");

        AtomEntry insertedEntry = myService.Insert(postUri, entry);
```

can anyone help me out with this? I've tried for basic and full both and removing private as well, is there something that I'm missing out on?

The calendar credentials that i m passing has access to the calendar and does have more than one calendar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know all of the Google API's require OAuth 2 authentication.  I'm not sure if your CalendarService class is using the Google API libraries or not.  It looks like your doing the authentication piece yourself?

I would highly recommend using the Google API .Net client to simplify all of this.  This library includes the Calendar API methods to make it really simple.

https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/

https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/OAuth2

Comment: Thanks, i figured out that my problem was in using "service" instantiation instead of using "myService" which is an instantiation of google.